# how to get ytd last year up to the same months this year in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

How to get the last year ytd vs the same months current year ytd in ssrs. Example, If my current year ytd is from Jan to March 2022, my last year ytd should be from Jan to March 2021 only but I'm getting all the months from my last year ytd as shown in the attached screen shot.
I have tried my best to really figure this out and read a lot of topics about this but nothing helps me. The below is the query I used to arrive my current year vs last year.

[image]

```
SELECT
  Sum(Amount) as GrossAmt
  ,Year(tranDate) as Year
  ,Month(tranDate) as Month
  ,SUM(CASE when YEAR(tranDate) = @Year -1 THEN Amount END) AS LYAmt
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(tranDate) = @Year THEN Amount END) AS ThisYAmt
FROM
  ( )
WHERE 
   Year(tranDate) BETWEEN @Year -1 and @Year
```

Thanks in advance to those who generously wants to help.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you only want to see the same months in both columns.

There are a few ways of doing this but a simple method that should give reasonable performance would be to simply put your results into a temp table then only return records where the months match in both years

something like....

```
SELECT
  Sum(Amount) as GrossAmt
  ,Year(tranDate) as Year
  ,Month(tranDate) as Month
  ,SUM(CASE when YEAR(tranDate) = @Year -1 THEN Amount END) AS LYAmt
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(tranDate) = @Year THEN Amount END) AS ThisYAmt
INTO #temp
FROM
  ( )
WHERE 
   Year(tranDate) BETWEEN @Year -1 and @Year

SELECT 
    a.*
FROM #temp a
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Month] FROM #temp WHERE [Year] = @Year) b
```

This will simply get a list of months for the current year (1 -3 in your exmaple) and filter the output to just those months.

---

**UPDATE AFTER OP FEEDBACK**

---

This shows how to use a data as a parameter `pEndDate` in SSRS and pass it to the dataset query to select the correct records.

This is based  on the old NorthWind sample database for illustration.

```
DECLARE @pEndDate date = '1998-03-15' -- comment out for production as this will be passed from the report

DECLARE @StartThisYear date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@pEndDate), 1, 1)
DECLARE @StartPreviousYear date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@pEndDate)-1, 1, 1)
DECLARE @EndDatePreviousYear date = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@pEndDate)-1, MONTH(@pEndDate), DAY(@pEndDate))

-- test we have the correct dates, comment out for production
SELECT @pEndDate, @StartThisYear, @StartPreviousYear, @EndDatePreviousYear

-- sample select statement selecting the correct data
SELECT *
  FROM [NorthWind].[dbo].[Orders] o 
    WHERE 
        (o.OrderDate BETWEEN @StartThisYear and @pEndDate
            OR 
        o.OrderDate BETWEEN @StartPreviousYear and @EndDatePreviousYear)
```

All we do here is take the end date, in the case March 15th 1998 and calculate the same date last year and the year start dates for the year that matches the parameter's year and also the previous year.

With the date parameter (`pEndDate`) set as 20th May 2022 you would have

```
@pEndDate = 2022-05-20
@StartThisYear  = 2022-01-01
@EndDatePreviousYear = 2021-05-20
@StartPreviousYear = 2021-01-01
```

Then all we do is select any record where the order date (in this example) is either between `@StartThisYear` and `@pEndDate' **OR** between` @StartPreviousYear`and`@EndDatePreviousYear`

Comment: Thanks sir! I would try this in some of the reports I need to create. I was able to resolve my question already. What I did was put a where condition in my month depending on what the end user inputs in the End Date parameter. By the way, any suggestion where and how to best start learning about sql queries? I'm a finance person, since no one is doing dashboards in the company im working, so I'm doing it myself. I came accross SSRS only 3 weeks ago and this interests me:)

Comment: I realized that If I do my query like this and put a where clause for the month, unfortunately, my last year ytd would cover up to the end of the month say Jan to May 31 even if my YTD this year is only up to say middle of the month of May 15. My objective is to have a dynamic date parameter so that the end user can have a comparative analysis at any given date according to what he would input in the End Date parameter. Do you have any suggestion how am I able to do this? by the way, I tried your suggestion Sir Alan but I can't seem to have it worked. Thanks! Regards - Mae

Comment: I'm really stuck on this, anyone pls who could help, would greatly appreciate it.